# Laravel - Json object showing empty ParameterBag

Tags: laravel

I have this JSON data sent in HTTP body in a post request.

```
{
    "id" : 238,
    "title": "Its a title",
    "description": "Its a description",
    "target_price": 3000,
    "date_of_availability": "16-02-2023",
    "condition": "abc",
    "latitude": "-31.953030",
    "longitude": "115.853600",
    "attributes": {
      "list" : [
        {
         "title" : "Color",
         "value" : "Red"
        },
        {
         "title" : "Frame",
         "value" : "Metal Frame"
        }
       ]
    }
  }
```

I want `attributes` to be stored in `json` data type field. I can get value of all other fields in my controller but when i `dd($request->attributes);` it show me empty Parameter Bag.

How can i get `$request->attributes` and store it in my `json` data type field of mysql.

**This is my migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('post_id')->generatedAs();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('target_price')->nullable();
        $table->date('date_of_availability')->nullable();
        $table->string('condition')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('latitude', 11, 8);
        $table->decimal('longitude', 11, 8);
        $table->json('attributes')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Here i am saving**

```
$post = new Post();
$post->title = $data->title;
$post->description = $data->description;
$post->target_price = $data->target_price;
$post->date_of_availability = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data->date_of_availability));;
$post->condition = $data->condition;
$post->latitude = $data->latitude;
$post->longitude = $data->longitude;
$post->attributes = $data->attributes;
$post->save();
```

This is the error i am getting for line `$post->attributes = $data->attributes;`

**"message": "Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string",**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laravel request object uses magic methods to access the parameters that are passed in the body of the request. This only works if the `Request` class doesn't already have a property of the same name.

The `Illuminate\Http\Request` class extends the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` class which has an explicit property called `$attributes`:

```php
/**
 * Custom parameters.
 *
 * @var ParameterBag
 */
public $attributes;
```

If you want to explicitly get a property from the request body without using the magic method you can use the `input` or `json` methods:

```
$post->attributes = $request->json('attributes');
```